# Правильное использование временных форм причастий и деепричастий

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастия

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли ошибкой использование причастий и деепричастий настоящего времени в предложениях, где речь идет о прошлом, и глаголы, соответственно, тоже стоят в прошедшем времени.
Примеры:
Котенок с трудом перебрался через лежащую на полу гантель. (Возможен вариант только с "лежавшую"?)
Галина недобрым взглядом посмотрела на соседа, постукивающего ладонями по спинке стула. (постукивавшего?)
Главное отличие этой улицы от предыдущих - проходящая сквозь нее ровная дорога, которая была окаймлена лежащими транспарантами, еще не убранными после митинга. (проходившая; лежавшими?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Котенок с трудом перебрался через **лежавшую** на полу гантель (временный признак).

Галина недобрым взглядом посмотрела на соседа, **постукивающего** ладонями по спинке стула (= в то время как тот постукивал).

Главное отличие этой улицы от предыдущих – **проходящая** (постоянный признак) сквозь нее ровная дорога, которая была окаймлена **лежавшими** (временный признак) транспарантами, еще не убранными после митинга.

**Эта тема у Розенталя:** [XLVIII. ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНЫЕ СИНТАКСИЧЕСКИЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm)

**Значение времени в причастии относительное**: в одних случаях наблюдается **соотносительность времен**, выраженных причастием и глаголом-сказуемым, например: видел детей, играющих на бульваре (видел **в то время, когда** они играли); в других случаях время, выраженное причастием, соотносится с **моментом речи**, предшествует ему, например: видел детей, игравших на бульваре. Ср.: а) В одной из комнат я нашел молодого парня, разбирающего за столом бумаги (В. Солоухин); б) В эту ночь, как нарочно, загорелись пустые сараи, принадлежавшие откупщикам (Герцен).

**При прошедшем времени глагола-сказуемого причастие настоящего времени указывает на постоянный признак, причастие прошедшего времени – на временный признак.** Например: Нас заинтересовал домик, стоящий на опушке леса (ср.: ...который стоит...). – Артем схватил тяжелый молот, стоявший у наковальни... (Н. Островский) (ср.: ...который стоял...).